# Function doGet doesn't work in Leave Approval script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am currently creating a leave application form using google script. After the user submits the form, it sends an email to a supervisor. The supervisor is able to approve or reject and able to state reason of rejection from the email itself. But the user receives both request pending email as well as need info email.

`````
function sendEmail(e) {
var Email = e.values[1];
var Name = e.values [2];
var LeadEmail = e.values [3]
var StartDate = e.values[4];
var EndDate = e.values[5];
var Reason = e.values[6];

var url ='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwtoHhUZPX2bEbbdiEjak4WwUZYBj5ulrSbUJlDzemgcqTMIG0/exec';
var resubmitFormUrl='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdNAeCsbTfntizgpMeOdbJdiWKRQKngo0hWsFaUmECFVMt94w/viewform?usp=sf_link'

var approve = url + '?approval=approve'+'&reply='+Email;
var reject = url + '?approval=reject'+'&reply='+Email;
var moreinfo = url + '?approval=moreinfo'+'&reply='+Email;

var html ="<body>"+
           "<h2>Please review</h2><br />"+
           
        "Email id : " + Email + "<br/>"+
          "Name : " + Name + "<br/>"+ 
            "Lead Email ID: " + LeadEmail + "<br/>"+
               "StartDate : " + StartDate + "<br/>"+
                  "EndDate : " + EndDate + "<br/>"+
                     "Reason : " + Reason + "<br/>"+
                  
                    "<a href ="+ approve +"> Approve</a><br />"+
                       "<a href ="+reject+">Reject</a> <br />"+
                         "<a href ="+moreinfo+">MoreInfo</a> <br />"+
         ```     "</body>";
          
  MailApp.sendEmail(LeadEmail, "Approval Request", "what no html?", {htmlBody: html});

var htmll ="<body>"+
           "<h3>You have submitted these details</h3>"+
          
          "Email id : " + Email + "<br/>"+
            "Name : " + Name + "<br/>"+ 
              "Lead Email ID: " + LeadEmail + "<br/>"+
                "StartDate : " + StartDate + "<br/>"+
                   "EndDate : " + EndDate + "<br/>"+
                      "Reason : " + Reason + "<br/>"+
                    
                  ```  "<h3>You'll be notified soon about the approval ```decision</h3>"+
            "<body/>";
                  
MailApp.sendEmail(Email,"Approval Request","What no html?",{htmlBody:htmll});

  var html2 ="<body>"+
          `` "<h3>You have submitted the below details,but Approver require more information</h3>"+
          
          "Email id : " + Email + "<br/>"+
            "Name : " + Name + "<br/>"+ 
              "Lead Email ID: " + LeadEmail + "<br/>"+
                "StartDate : " + StartDate + "<br/>"+
                   "EndDate : " + EndDate + "<br/>"+
                      "Reason : " + Reason + "<br/>"+
                       
                    
                    "<h3>click the link </h3><a href = "+resubmitFormUrl+">Re-Submit </a> <h3>form for Approval</h3>  "+
                    
                   "<h3>You'll be notified soon about the approval decision</h3>"+
            "<body/>";
                  
````MailApp.sendEmail(Email,"Approval Request","What no html?",{htmlBody:html2});

}
           
function doGet(e)
{
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval==="approve") ? 'is Approved': (e.parameter.approval==="reject") ? 'Not approved' : 'Requires More Information' ;
  
  var msg = "Your leave is: " + answer ;
  if(e.parameter.approval != "moreinfo")
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply,"Approval Request",msg);  
  
 
}
`````

Expected: Once a user submits the request form

1. Acknowledgement email to the user along with approval email to the supervisor should be sent
2. Upon clicking on Approve link, an email should sent to the user stating leave has been approved.
3. Upon clicking on Reject link, an email should sent to the user stating leave has been rejected.
4. Upon clicking on Need Info link, an email should sent to the user asking him to submit more information as to why he is seeking leave should be sent

My apologies if I have made a mistake, I'm still a beginner. Therefore, request you to help me please.

Comment: You should change the name of your first function from `sendEmail()`, the method from `MailApp` is also called that, also, from that same function you're calling `MailApp.sendEmail()` twice after you build the `html` variable, so it will. Lastly, your webApp URL will always be the same, I suggest you take a look at [passing parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) to it see how you can have better-constructed URLs (have one for accepted, rejected or need more info)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing `doGet` like this could help? (I can't test it to be sure):

```
function doGet(e) {
  var answer = '';

  // Checks for each value ('approve', 'reject', or 'moreinfo') separately
  //   Now, 'moreinfo' is not assumed by default (might matter)
  if (e.parameter.approval === "approve") { answer = 'is Approved'; }  
  else if (e.parameter.approval === "reject") { answer = 'Not approved'; }
  else if (e.parameter.approval === "moreinfo") { answer = 'Requires More Information'; }

  // In case e.parameter.approval somehow matches none of the above
  else { answer = "Undetermined yet -- please contact us"; }

  var msg = "Your leave is: " + answer;

  // Uses strict equality (might matter)
  if (e.parameter.approval !== "moreinfo"){

    // Includes curly braces around statement (probably unnecessary)
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Approval Request", msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cat. Appreciate your help, but when the script runs, it sends two emails at the same time to the user who has applied for leave. Also, Need Info link does nothing upon hitting